# How to create a drop down menu in an ASP.NET control page .ascx with the no: of items in the menu changing dynamically

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, dhtml, ascx

I want to add a drop down menu control to my .ascx ASP.NET control page. The elements of the drop down menu are the years from 2006 to current year. Since the current year keeps on changing with time, the elements in drop down menu should also change dynamically.

I could have used the foll code snippet if the no: of elements in the menu were static.

```
<select id=f1  onchange="eventHandler(this)">
 <option value="2009">2009</option>
 <option value="2010">2010</option>
 <option value="2011" selected=selected>2011</option> </select>
```

Can anyone Kindly let me know how to achieve this using HTML/ Javascript code in my ASP.NET control .ascx page.

Thnaks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Place the following code in .ascx file

and in page load place the following code

```
int curYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
for (Int32 year = 2006; year <= curYear; year++)
{
  DropDownList1.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(year));
}
```